# Injecting custom code between divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a Slick-slider, that looks like this on desktop:

```html
<div class="regular slider">
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
</div>
```

On mobile, I'm trying to make the structure become:

```html
<div class="regular slider">
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>1</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>2</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>3</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>4</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>5</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>6</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>7</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>8</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
</div>
```

I can't 'just have them as singles' and then setting `slidesToShow: 4` on desktop, since I need them in a grid, where they're displayed on top of one another, like so:

```
      -------
       1 | 2
<<    -------    >>
       3 | 4
      -------
```

So they need the container on desktop. But I would like to make it so the user can scroll through the entities one at a time on mobile devices.

Are there a way, where I can inject

```html
</div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
<div class="slick__single-slide">
```

in between... ehm... some of the divs inside my slider? This is a terrible problem. I know. :-/

Comment: Why not have 2 sets of sliders?

Comment: Then the content would be loaded twice, which would slow down the site. But I'm very close to just doing that, because I'm sick of this issue. :-)

Comment: Lazy load elements instead of all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some DOM manipulations:

1. Move the inner `div`s to the parent (`.slider`)
2. Add the class `.slick__single-slide` to each.
3. Wrap their inner content (the number) with `div`.

I show the output html in a `pre` tag so it could be easy to see the result.

```js
$('.slick__single-slide div').unwrap().addClass('slick__single-slide').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().wrap('<div />');
});
$('pre').text($('.slider')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="regular slider">
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
  <div class="slick__single-slide">
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div><!-- /.slick__single-slide -->
</div>

The updated html:
<pre></pre>
```